# When I try to insert subdoc into mongodb with the help of mongoose,It returns “cannot use the part (...”

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this really annoying issue where i can't update anything using Mongoose. It's really frustrating to use, and the documentation is not helping at all.

Here is my schema:

```
var CRMModel = mongoose.model('CRM', new Schema({
    title: { type: String, index: true }
  , author: String
  , remarks: String
  , date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  comments:[{
          title:String,
          seq:Number,
          date:{ type: Date, default: Date.now() }
        }]
  })
);
```

And this is the code where I want to add a comment to the array `comments` :

```
CRMModel.update({_id:crmId.trim()},{ $push: { 'comments.title':         req.body.title, 'comments.seq': req.body.seq} },
       {upsert:true},
       function(err, customer){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           }
       }
   );
```

At this point I get the error:

```
{ [MongoError: cannot use the part (comments of comments.title) to    traverse the element ({comments: []})]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'cannot use the part (comments of comments.title) to  traverse the element ({comments: []})',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'cannot use the part (comments of comments.title) to traverse  the element ({comments: []})' }
```

I have looked for the similar problems on Stack Overflow but I did't solve this. I will be grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "argument" to `$push` should be an array field, which in your case is `comments`:

```
{
  $push : {
    comments : {
      title : req.body.title,
      seq   : req.body.seq
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I solve the problem with your codes.Your help really save me from stuck in this problem and I can have a rest now.   O(∩_∩)O